# Yeast pitching and wort cooling

Tags: yeast, temperature, pitching, brown-ale

I'm making an American Brown Ale and added liquid yeast to the wort that may have been too hot. The yeast was in the fridge and out to cool for 45 minutes. My guess is:

Wort temp: 26-27C or about 80F

Liquid yeast temp: 8C or about 47F

1. Does it sound like I killed the yeast?
2. If so, what kind of dry yeast should I get to add to the beer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yeast will survive. Most yeast will survive up to 30C, and some strains up to 40C. The pitching temperature is high, so you will probably get some off flavors from that, namely,  more fruitiness from increased ester production, and a hot alcohol taste from fusel alcohols (think bad whiskey.)

If you can chill the wort down to 18C that would be ideal to reduce the impact of the high pitching temperature.

Answer (score 5):

If your wort was at 80°F/27°C, you definitely didn't kill your yeast. Yeast thrive at temperatures well into the 90s, and can survive significantly higher.

You don't want to ferment at that temperature, though, and likewise you don't want to pitch that warm because immediately dropping the temperature can cause your yeast to flocculate early.